# Use Docker environment variables for credentials

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Recently we are trying to find a proper way of injecting credentials via environment variables to the spring based application we run in the container.

The exact process includes

- A bootstrap shell script, which docker CMD runs as an entry point
- Export bunch of credentials inside the script
- Run the application at the end of the script file

With this way, none of `docker inspect`, `docker exec [container_id] env`or bash into docker container and run `env` will see these environment variables, ie. what we injected with bootstrap script are opaque.

So the question: is there anything else we should consider with this solution? any obvious glitches?

We are pretty new to docker world, so this behaviour, about making environment variables injected by shell script are not visible since after, is there any document explaining why? we haven't found a good doc but just found it's working in this way

PS. will docker change this behaviour in future?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you store the script? A file on the host? Or build it into the image? Is it a concern that the script source file can be seen?

Comment: The script is stored in the image, additionally, we've used HashiCorp Consul and Vault, so the script calls local Vault command for retrieving credentials from the other Consul container and that all happens in runtime on container startup, ie. no credentials are with the script in the image it goes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a very good approach overall.

However, I don't think you can complete hide the environment variables from someone who has permissions to inspect process envs. It seems to me that if you find out the process id of the application process (inside the container or from the host) you should be able to find its environment in `/proc`. Won't show up as `docker env`, but it's still in there somewhere.
Also, any such person can probably connect to your Vault directly anyway.

Meaning, yes, this will reliably not make the environment of child processes show up in the container environment, but it does not really hide it from anyone (who can already access your host machine and control docker).

Still, congrats on this setup. Much better than having credentials built into images.

Comment: We would take unauthorised access to host or inside container a 'hack' from there. Idea is at host level to restrict user from using some certain docker commands (probably need custom code for it) eg. the docker exec [id] bash

Comment: @JamesJiang @Thilo It is fairly easy to get the environment for a Docker process from the host (or container). Just use `ps aux` to find the process id, and use `cat /proc/id/environ` to get all env variables. Also, if a user can run `docker` commands, likely he also has `sudo` rights.

Comment: @warmoveflow agree with inspecting /prod/id/environ for these variables is a valid way of reaching out to credentials. However, you don't have to worry about leaking credentials from docker images in build time neither inspectable environment variables from containers runtime, ie. the concern is leveraged from container itself to the host now. If the host is not exposed to the public network, but well protected by firewall or private networking, and user privileges, this should be a viable solution right?

Comment: Yes, that's what we are saying: a) you cannot protect the credentials from someone with host access b) your approach is good to protect the credentials from anyone else (it comes down to how you secure the Vault) -- that the env does not directly appear in docker env is nonconsequential

Answer (score 0):

Interesting find. I think that is because the environment variables are local to the shell session where your app is running. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

> **Process locality**
>
> The values of environment variables are local, which means they are
>   specific to the running process in or for which they were set. This
>   means that if we open two terminal windows (which means we have two
>   separate bash processes running), and change a value of an environment
>   variable in one of the windows, that change will not be seen by the
>   shell in the other window or any other program currently on the
>   desktop.

Regarding risk, there is a good discussion here https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9176#issuecomment-99542089. For example, you might have debug apps in the same session that prints out or logs the environment, any child processes also see the environment variable.